# merging to master two branches with previous common history

Tags: git

I'm asking about problem related to this: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt

I have three branches: master, A and B. I merged B to A. But later it turned out to be a mistake so I made revert of this merge. I know that now it is impossible to do another B to A merge (because I can lose the changes from B before the revert), I should first do revert of revert of this merge and then merge B to A.

And here comes the master... What if after first revert of merge, someone will merge B to master and then A to master? Or in reverse order? Will the changes from B before the first revert be on the master?

Can anyone help me?

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this history (time flows left to right):

```
-o--o--o--o           <- master
  \
   a--a--a---M--R     <- branch A
    \       /
     b--b--b          <- branch B
```

`R` is the reversal of them merge `M`.

> What if after first revert of merge, someone will merge B to master and then A to master? Or in reverse order? Will the changes from B before the first revert be on the master?

That is, you get this history:

```
-o--o--o--o--X----Y    <- master
 |          /     |
 |   b--b--b      |    <- branch B
  \ /       \    /
   a--a--a---M--R      <- branch A
```

Here, first `B` was merged to `master`, then `A`. As you can see, the reversal is now part of `master`, and so are the changes that it brought, i.e. it undoes the changes of branch `B`. You can see that `X` and all commits up to, but excluding, `Y` have the changes of branch `B`, but `Y` and later have these changes reverted.

If, on the other hand, branch `A` was merged first, then branch `B` (as well as its reversal commit `R`) is already included in the merge. `git merge B` would tell you: "Already up to date".

Comment: so what is the best solution now? revert of revert of this merge on branch A and then merge both (branch A and B) to master? is there aby better way to solve this situation? or was there any way to get out of the situation earlier - instead of do revert of merge do something else?

Comment: Neither did you specify what you want to achieve nor what your constraints are. There are many things you could do, but which one you *should* do, depends on so many things.